# How to find database time overlap

Tags: sql, database

I'm creating database to check if `Room` is available for entered time. And I'm having a problem with writing the query. Query must check `Schedule` table and `Reservation` table if there is overlap with entered time. It will be the best that query return `TRUE` if there is a overlap and `FALSE` if there isn't. Is this good database structure for that (so I can focus only on query) or I need to restructure database? Please help me.

My database:

```
CREATE TABLE "Room" (
    "ID" VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  UNIQUE,
    "Name" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "Location" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "Capacity" INTEGER
)

CREATE TABLE "Schedule" (
    "ID" VARCHAR,
    "Day" VARCHAR,
    "start_time" DATETIME,
    "end_time" DATETIME
)

CREATE TABLE "Reservation" (
    "ID" VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
    "Day" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    " start_time " DATETIME NOT NULL,
    " end_time " DATETIME NOT NULL,
    "User" VARCHAR
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the appropriate data type for each column, the "ID" columns better be `INT`. What do you need the "Day" columns for? There's a date in your "start_time" and "end_time" columns anyway.

Also I don't see a connection between the "Room" table and the other two.

```
CREATE TABLE "Room" (
    "ID" INT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  UNIQUE,
    "Name" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "Location" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "Capacity" INT
)

CREATE TABLE "Schedule" (
    ID INT,
    start_time DATETIME,
    end_time DATETIME,
    room_id INT
)

CREATE TABLE "Reservation" (
    "ID" INT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
    "start_time " DATETIME NOT NULL,
    "end_time " DATETIME NOT NULL,
    "User" VARCHAR /*you might want to make this an INT, too, and put the users in an extra table*/
    , room_id INT
)
```

I don't know what DBMS you are using, so I also don't know correct syntax, but you better put a foreign key on the room_id columns in Schedule and Reservation tables referencing id column in Room table.

Then you do it like this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
Room 
LEFT JOIN Schedule ON Room.id = Schedule.room_id
LEFT JOIN Reservation ON Room.id = Reservation.room_id
WHERE 
(
(Schedule.start_time <= $yourStartTime AND Schedule.end_time > $yourEndTime)
OR
(Reservation.start_time <= $yourStartTime AND Reservation.end_time > $yourEndTime)
) 
AND Room.id = $yourRoomId
```

This query returns something when the room is full and nothing / NULL when the room is free.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can you check your query once again because it returns NULL although room is not available for selected time. I'm working with sqlite database and I will use it in Android application.

Comment: The logic of this query is fine. Are you sure your parameter is datetime? This query assumes your parameter is something like this `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. Of course it might be in a slightly different format, but be sure your parameter is casted as datetime.

Comment: And you have also made the changes to the table schemas? Notice, I added `room_id` columns to "Reservation" and "Schedule". And you filled those columns with data? Just asking to be sure.

Comment: I changed start_time AND end_time to INT, so I can easier test it.

Comment: Well, then it must be this: `end_time > $yourEndTime`. Change it to `>=`. If this also doesn't help, please provide sample data. It's hard to guess around.

Comment: Hey friend, how would you write that query to return something when room is free and nothing when room is full? Vice versa from present.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't. When a room is free, there is no entry in the database so a query will have an empty set as result. There's even no way to handle this with `COALESCE(room_id, 'There is no room')` function. This function returns the first non-null parameter. The best way is to handle this in your application code, not in the database. I'm not saying it's impossible, but believe me, it's like someone shoots you from the back through to the chest into the eye.